# A couple questions on the generalized eigenspaces of a nonself-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $A:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a compact (not necessarily self-adjoint) linear operator on a Hilbert space. Suppose $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ is non-zero. Using the compactness of $A$, one can show that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that:

\begin{equation}
\text{ker}\left(A- \lambda \right)^m = \text{ker}\left(A- \lambda \right)^{m+1} \ \ \ \ \forall m \geq n 
\end{equation}

and that $Y_{\lambda} \equiv \ker\left(A- \lambda \right)^n $ is finite dimensional. Let $P_{\lambda}$ be the orthogonal projection onto $Y_\lambda$.

I would like some help showing a few things. Its clear that $\text{Ran}P_{\lambda}=Y_{\lambda}$ is A invariant, but I'm having trouble showing $\ker P_{\lambda}= Y_{\lambda}^{\perp}$ is A invariant. I would prefer to do this without appealing to the fact that the projection operator equals:

\begin{equation}
P_{\lambda} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\gamma} (\lambda -A)^{-1}d\lambda
\end{equation}
for a small contour ${\gamma}$ around the isolated point $\lambda$ of $\sigma(A)$.

Edit:
Also, I would like to show that $Y_{\lambda} \perp Y_{\mu}$ for $\lambda \neq \mu \neq0$, (I can show $Y_{\lambda} \bigcap Y_{\mu}=\{0\}$)  again without apprealing to the above contour integral formulation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to show is false, even for a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$. For example, start with a basis of non-orthogonal vectors
$$
        x_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right],\;x_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right].
$$
Define $A$ by $A(\alpha x_{1}+\beta x_{2})=2\alpha x_{1}+3\beta x_{2}$. Then $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ are eigenvectors and, using your notation, $Y_{2}$ is the linear span of $x_{1}$. But $Y_{2}^{\perp}$, which is the linear span of $\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$, is not invariant under $A$. Clearly $Y_{2}$ is not orthogonal to $Y_{3}$ because $x_{1}$ is not orthogonal to $x_{2}$.